# Why float won't increase at some point while computing FLT_MAX by summation?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compute `FLT_MAX` from `<float.h>` with the following code:

```
float increase(float a, float step)
{
    float t = a, original = a;
    while((t = a + step) > a)
    {
        a = t;
    }

    if(original == a)
    {
        printf(" %lf was not increased with %lf step \n", original, step);
        return a;
    }
    printf(" %lf increased to %lf with %lf step \n", original, a, step);
    return increase(a, step / 100.0);
}


void main()
{
    printf("FLT_MAX : %f \n", FLT_MAX);

    // compute:
    increase(0.0, 10.0);
    increase(0.0, 100.0);
    increase(0.0, 10000.0);
    increase(0.0, 100000000.0);
    increase(0.0, 10000000000000000.0);
}
```

It outputs:

```
FLT_MAX : 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000000
 0.000000 increased to 268435456.000000 with 10.000000 step
 268435456.000000 was not increased with 0.100000 step
 0.000000 increased to 2147483648.000000 with 100.000000 step
 2147483648.000000 was not increased with 1.000000 step
 0.000000 increased to 274877906944.000000 with 10000.000000 step
 274877906944.000000 was not increased with 100.000000 step
 0.000000 increased to 2251799813685248.000000 with 100000000.000000 step
 2251799813685248.000000 was not increased with 1000000.000000 step
 0.000000 increased to 302231454903657290000000.000000 with 10000000272564224.000000 step
 302231454903657290000000.000000 was not increased with 100000000376832.000000 step
```

Why it stops the increase at those points while there seems to be some space? And it looks like it needs some bits manipulations to get `FLT_MAX` or is it possible to get it by summing? Thanks!

Comment: The increment becomes too small eventually.

Comment: The *float* type has 7 significant digits at best so you can only increase it when you add at least `a * 1E-7`.  Multiplication would be the better way.

Comment: take a look at IEEE 754. How does the float compute.

Comment: the logic of the posted code causes a return to caller if a larger step fails to increase the value.  So the recursion never occurs when a larger step does not increase the value.   Suggest re-design the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original code stopped at various places because `float` values are distributed logarithmically and have finite precision.  There are about as many `float` values in the range [1000000 to 2000000] as there are between [0.0000001 to 0.0000002].  At some point adding a small `float` to a large `float` does not distinguish between consecutive `float` values.

Code is close to working.

At the end of the while loop, code needs to

1) Try larger steps if some increase occurs or
2) Try adding smaller steps if steps are not too small  (this was missing)  or
3) Return

Also step *changes* should be a small factor like *2.0 or /2.0 rather than 100.0.  Detection of infinity added

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float increase(float a, float step) {
  fflush(stdout);
  float t = a, original = a;
  while ((t = a + step) > a) {
    if (1.0f/t == 0.0f) break;
    a = t;
  }
  if (original == a) {
    printf(" %lf was not increased with %lf step \n", original, step);
    if (step > 1.0) return increase(a, step / 2.0);
    return a;
  }
  printf(" %lf increased to %lf with %lf step \n", original, a, step);
  return increase(a, step * 2.0);
}

//void main() {
int main(void) {
  printf("FLT_MAX : %f \n", FLT_MAX);

  // compute:
  increase(0.0, 10.0);
//  increase(0.0, 100.0);
//  increase(0.0, 10000.0);
//  increase(0.0, 100000000.0);
//  increase(0.0, 10000000000000000.0);
  printf("FLT_MAX : %f \n", FLT_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
FLT_MAX : 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 
0.000000 increased to 268435456.000000 with 10.000000 step 
...
340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 was not increased with 0.625000 step 
FLT_MAX : 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
```

Comment: It works. Though it is not clear to me with the detection of infinity now.

Comment: OK. 0x7f800000, infinity as a divider gets zero. Looks like some compiler introduced check for that value to comply with real world.